# Error: must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code, csc

Having a bit of an issue getting this error to clear when compiling with `csc.exe` on Win10. I am very new to C#. Doing a bit of self learning before I start attending classes in Jan.

Following a "TeamTreehouse" tutorial on doing this. They are using `mono` in their workspaces. I am preferring to use `vscode` on my machine to get familiar with using C# outside of mono.

From what I have read on CS0501 with my issue is that it is a compiler issue that shouldn't be an issue but using `csc.exe` is causing an issue. Adding `abstract` gives a whole new set of issues.

Command using to compiler from terminal is `csc *.cs`

I am not sure where to look next for a solution. I haven't been able to find a working one using what is called `Auto-Implemented Properties`.

**The error is**

> Invader.cs(6,39): error CS0501: 'TreehouseDefense.Invader.Location.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern
>
> Invader.cs(6,52): error CS0501: 'TreehouseDefense.Invader.Location.set' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern

**The code**
Invader.cs

```
namespace TreehouseDefense {

    class Invader {

        public MapLocation Location { get; private set; }

    }
}
```

**The Project**
Object_Project.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I think, your problem is compiler that is of early version that does not support Auto-property

Comment: I think for .NET Core projects, you should be using the [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x) command. Or just use the Build command from within VSCode.

Comment: @itsme86 `msbuild` works too

Comment: When you run just "csc" what version number does it show?

Comment: @itsme86 `dotnet build` is working to compile it looks like but it is not generating an exe. Also just found `dotnet publish` which is creating over 200 files rather than a self contained exe like `csc` does

Comment: @JonSkeet `Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2005 Compiler version 8.00.50727.8745
for Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 2005 Framework version 2.0.50727
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2001-2005. All rights reserved.` is what it shows

Comment: `dotnet publish` shouldn't create 200 files unless you've got that many dependencies - in which case you'd need those files anyway. Not that I'd use it most of the time - just `dotnet run` is fine generally.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the C# 2 compiler, from 2005. C# 2 didn't support automatically implemented properties - along with all kinds of other features which are part of modern C#.

You want to be running a C# 7 compiler. I'd suggest installing [Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), and using the Visual Studio 2017 Command Prompt so that the right version of `csc` is on the path.

Or just download the [.NET Core SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) and use the `dotnet` command to build and run instead of `csc`.

Comment: Thanks for this. This led me to to a bunch of new articles I hadn't found. Posted a solution I was able to get to work.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone for help with this. It got me pointed in a good direction. Have been doing a bit more reading and found this as a solution. The following way is the easiest way I found that could make a self contained EXE. I was not able to get `dotnet build`, `dotnet publish`, or `msbuild` to work. Still have a lot to learn.

This will install `Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.10.0.0 (b9fb1610)`

- Install `NuGet v4.8.1` [Link to Download](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)
- Opened `NuGet` in `Command Prompt` and ran `nuget install Microsoft.Net.Compilers`
- Moved the package it downloaded to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET`
- Added a new Environment Variable to `PATH` with `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\tools` (Also moved it above the existing one I had, could be removed as well)

`csc *.cs` now makes a self contained EXE